# How to write the mod_rewrite rules for these requirements?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need to make rules for mod_rewrite:

---

from

```
http://site.kiev.ua/index.php
http://www.site.kiev.ua/
http://www.site.kiev.ua/index.php
```

to

```
http://site.kiev.ua/
```

---

from

```
http://site.kiev.ua/catalog/products/941
```

to

```
http://site.kiev.ua/catalog/products/941/
```

---

from

```
http://site.kiev.ua/catalog/products/941/index.php
```

to

```
http://site.kiev.ua/catalog/products/941/
```

---

941 - it may be any category

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localised for one user, and is probably not useful for readers in the future (we have thousands of write-my-mod-rewrite-rules-for-me questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# www to none www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+/)?index\.(html?|php)(\?.*)?\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index\.(html?|php)$ ./$1 [R=301,L]

# Force trailing slashes.
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# /file.php to /file/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/.*[^/])/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ ./$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but with rule, that removes index.php it getting loop on domain.com ....

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ $1`

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.site\.kiev\.ua$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.kiev.ua/$1 [L,R=301]
```